# on substance (expression)

Tags: meaning

Source: [Obama and Putin Move Toward Compromise on Syria](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2015-09-29/obama-and-putin-move-toward-a-syria-compromise?cmpid=yhoo)

Example:

> Both leaders obviously needed to vent before they went face to face. **On substance**, though, Obama showed the weaker hand. He stressed his reluctance to submit to the logic according to which some unsavory regimes -- "tyrants like Bashar al-Assad, who drops barrel bombs to massacre innocent children" -- should be supported to beat back terrorism.

What exactly does that mean? How do you personally understand that?

Comment: This usage reminds me of **[in substance](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/in-substance)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is an analysis of speeches given by the two leaders.

"Of substance" is generally used to mean "significant" in some way. A "man of substance" is likely to be someone who has made a contribution to the world.

It has become a shorthand in the media to talk about "substance" when discussing political speech in order to distinguish saying something meaningful/significant/substantial from rhetoric and posturing.

So the quote means that when you pare the fluff out of Obama's speech there was less real significance than there was in Putin's on the whole.